# Can't access assets when adding these rewriterules to .htaccess

Tags: regex, .htaccess, url-rewriting

In my php project I used root-relative paths to access frontend-assets (js,css,images) like:

- /assets/css/styles.css
- /assets/javascripts/anyscript.js

So what the browser is looking for is

[document root]/assets/javascripts/anyscript.js

When adding these rules to .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(.+)/?$ index.php?page=$1&actions=$2 [L]

#Can't get it going with that.
#RewriteRule ^(?:([^/]+)/)+([^/]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1&url=$2 [L]
```

I'm able to access pages and controllers via urls like:

- //localhost/signin/
- //localhost/signin/sessionController/testingMethod
- //localhost/signin/sessionController/testingMethod/parameter1/parameter2

But not the assets in the assets-folder anymore:

- //localhost/assets/javascripts/somejs.js?v=123

When checking the requests in the browser console, the paths that are requested seem to be correct but I get a 404 response when he requests it.

What do I need to change to access the assets like js, css and images that are located in

[document root]/assets folder?

---

### EDIT:

Following URL-Schemes need to be redirected:

```
old => //localhost/index.php?page=signin
new => //localhost/signin

old => //localhost/index.php?page=signin&action=someController/someMethod
new => //localhost/signin/someController/someMethod

old => //localhost/index.php?page=signin&action=someController/someMethod/param1/param2
new => //localhost/signin/someController/someMethod/param1/param2
```

Not Sure how to solve this one - but doesn't need to be solved yet:

```
old => //localhost/index.php?action=/someController/someMethod
new => //localhost/someController/someMethod
```

Answer (score 0):

The third example URL, for me, ends up as:

```
https://localhost/index.php?page=assets%26actions=javascripts/somejs.js
```

And that URL cannot work. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/AzBn1X/1).
It is not fully clear what needs to be redirect and what not but let's try this instead:

```
^(?:([^/]+)/)+([^/]+)/?$
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried to improve the question based on your answer and replaced the second rule with yours so it looks like this RewriteRule ^(?:([^/]+)/)+([^/]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1&url=$2 [L] can't get it going.